# Position/order for "Low", "Medium", "High" options

Tags: forms, gui-design, user-expectation, conventions, options

Is there any convention about positions/order to display options buttons/radio- buttons/checkboxes for values as:

*"Very low","Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"*

for attributes as Impact, Risk, Weight,....

would it be valid in the opposite direction?

*"Very High","High", "Medium","Low", "Very Low"*

For me it seems more common to see "Low" on the left and "High" on the right.
But i woulds like to know it is a convention or it depends on its positive/negative connotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it is useful to imagine what the options would be if they were numbers instead of words.

Let's say your question is: *"On a scale of 1-5, how likely are you to buy this product again?"*

Now, you would never even think to question which order to use. The answer would always be start with "1" on the left, and "5" on the right (assuming a left-to-right language).

So the trick is, don't let "words" convince your that it should be any different.

If I change the question: *"How likely are you to buy this product again?"*

Imagine them as numbers. It would seem fairly obvious that "very low" should equal 1, and "very high" should equal 5. And there you have your answer.

In addition, as a rule of thumb: if you can't see an obvious reason to chose one order over the other, then there is a good chance that the order doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: The statement "It would seem fairly obvious that 'very low' should equal 1, and 'very high' should equal 5" seems unsubstantiated.  While the ordering of 1-5 seems natural for a LTR language, it's not necessarily clear what 1 and 5 *mean*.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Well we have established that 1 = low (less likely) and 5 = high (more likely). So when you have a range of terms that have "very low" at one end and "very high" at the other, we already know that 1 = low, and 5 = high. So that determines the order of the options.